# grouping variable to create subset

Tags: r

i want a subset can be created for grouping variables so that i can apply function like

```
R1=c(1,5),R2=(3)
crosstab_sum(dat1 = dataa,var1 = "col1",grouping_var = "region",filter_val = c(R1,R2....))
```

Comment: It feels like your previous approach is a little complicated. You can draw any kind of subset using filter conditions. For example, if you only want to have the cases with region 1 and 5, just write `subset = dataa[dataa$region %in% c(1,5),]`. For this subset you may then compute any number of summaries. If you want to do it for several subsets, use a for-loop to loop through different conditions. WARNING: Your code in the last chunk won't work as c(R1,R2) would result in the vector c(1,5,3). There are no nested vectors in R. Use a list to organize vectors.

Comment: What is `cro_cpct` ?

Comment: cro_cpct is function in EXPSS package to create summary like SPSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I have managed to create subset then to apply function accordingly.
now it works perfectly fine...

```
P1 <- subset (dataa, cat== c("v","d","u"))
P2<- subset (dataa, cat== c("n","s")
```

thanks @Martin Wettstein for your suggestions...